# Embedding VLC in WPF Application using Visual Studio 2012 (Adding Control to Toolbar not working)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, activex, vlc

I have seen many questions and solutions to embed VLC in a WPF project but they all seem to be many years old and none of them are using Visual Studio 2012.

I know the code behind I need to set up the player but getting the ActiveX plugin into my toolbox has been an issue.

I installed the latest version of VLC (2.1.5) and it will not allow me to add the COM component to the toolbox or even add a reference to the VLC Plugin to my project.

When I tried installing previous versions of VLC this occurred as well. The only recent version that allowed me to at least reference it in my project was version 2.0.5. but adding it to the toolbox was a problem.

I'm even experiencing this issue in Visual Studio 2010.

If anyone has any current links or solutions to this problem for VS 2010 or preferably VS 2012, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your project 32 or 64 bit?